# Is it 3-D Catalan numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, 3d, catalan-numbers

I am studying Catalan numbers recently but I think that how about 3-D Catalan? 
So that I imagine following situation ;

> A man travel through the path-way parallel to   $  x, y, z $ axis from O $(0, 0, 0)$ to  $P (n, n, n)$ $ (n \in  N)$
>   However he chooses the Points  $(x, y, z)$  satisfy   $ x \leq   y \leq z $  , and the path-way is always the shortest way  $(x, y, z \in  Z)$
>   during all his trip. 
>   What number of path-ways he can choose in his trip?

Abobe situation , 
This is my question.

Comment: You want *my* advice ? Determine the first few terms of this “three-dimensional” Catalan sequence, and then [check to see if by any chance it's not already known](http://oeis.org).

Comment: The answer for this question is $\frac{2{\cdot}(3n)!}{(n+2)!{\cdot}(n+1)!{\cdot}n!}.$
https://oeis.org/A005789

Comment: Multidimensional Catalan numbers have been studied.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The problem from 2017 Cayley Contest of CEMC from University of Waterloo]

The problem from 2017 Cayley Contest of CEMC of University of Waterloo is about 3D Catalan Number.  The answer is: $\frac{2\cdot(3n)!}{n!\cdot(n+1)!\cdot(n+2)!} = \frac{2\cdot9!}{3!\cdot4!\cdot5!} = 42$